# Java SparkSql 2.4.0 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and trying to read a CSV file using Java maven project but getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();

    //Read file
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
            .format("csv")
            .load("test.csv");
```

CSV File

```
name,code
A,1
B,3
C,5
```

Here is stacktrace

```
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.0
    18/11/12 11:16:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Java Spark SQL Example
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: vkumar
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: vkumar
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
    18/11/12 11:16:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(vkumar); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(vkumar); groups with modify permissions: Set()
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54382.
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/32/7klbv5_94wbddn9kgzvbwnkr0000gn/T/blockmgr-ddd2a79d-7fae-48e4-9658-1a8e2a8bb734
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 4.1 GB
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://kirmac133.domain.com:4040
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54383.
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on kirmac133.domain.com:54383
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, kirmac133.domain.com, 54383, None)
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager kirmac133.domain.com:54383 with 4.1 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, kirmac133.domain.com, 54383, None)
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, kirmac133.domain.com, 54383, None)
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, kirmac133.domain.com, 54383, None)
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/Users/vkumar/Documents/intellij/tmvalidator/spark-warehouse').
    18/11/12 11:16:26 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/Users/vkumar/Documents/intellij/tmvalidator/spark-warehouse'.
    18/11/12 11:16:27 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
    18/11/12 11:16:28 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pruning directories with: 
    18/11/12 11:16:28 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters: (length(trim(value#0, None)) > 0)
    18/11/12 11:16:28 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Output Data Schema: struct<value: string>
    18/11/12 11:16:28 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Pushed Filters: 
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 130.688148 ms
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10582
    at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.accept(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:563)
    at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer$ClassReader.access$200(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:338)
    at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.BytecodeReadingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(BytecodeReadingParanamer.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.paranamer.CachingParanamer.lookupParameterNames(CachingParanamer.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.getCtorParams(BeanIntrospector.scala:44)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$1$adapted(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.findConstructorParam$1(BeanIntrospector.scala:58)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$19(BeanIntrospector.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:194)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$14(BeanIntrospector.scala:170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.$anonfun$apply$14$adapted(BeanIntrospector.scala:169)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.BeanIntrospector$.apply(BeanIntrospector.scala:169)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$._descriptorFor(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:22)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$.fieldName(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaAnnotationIntrospector$.findImplicitPropertyName(ScalaAnnotationIntrospectorModule.scala:78)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:467)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:283)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueMethod(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:169)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueMethod(BasicBeanDescription.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:210)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1203)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:481)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:679)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3559)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope.toJson(RDDOperationScope.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3384)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$12(DataSource.scala:183)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at kir.com.tmvalidator.Validator.init(Validator.java:30)
    at kir.com.tmvalidator.Home.main(Home.java:7)
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://kirmac133.domain.com:4040
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 4
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
    18/11/12 11:16:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/32/7klbv5_94wbddn9kgzvbwnkr0000gn/T/spark-1bde2bb5-603d-4fae-9128-7d92f259077b
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: @shriyog - Added

Comment: Are you getting this error of above-mentioned input in csv?

Comment: @shriyog - Yes :(

Comment: I tested the same for `2.3.0` versions, it works without issues. Checking with `2.4.0`

Comment: @shriyog - Thank you. Also just to add. I am on Mac and using IntelliJ to create a maven project. I have not installed anything on my mac and just using dependencies.

Comment: Did you try this *"com.databricks.spark.csv"* for the format? I prefer databricks schema over the Spark default option. More info here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: What's the solution for version 2.4, I meet the same problem while version 2.3 works well for me!
I'm using java edition.

Answer (score 8):

The paranamer version referred in Spark 2.4.0 is 2.7 which is causing the issue. Adding following dependency before the spark-core/ spark-sql solved the issue for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, but when I tried scala, this problem solved!

val tp = StructType(Seq(StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType), StructField("code", DataTypes.IntegerType)))

val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(tp).load("test.csv")